# CSS Floating issue with text and images

Tags: php, html, css, positioning

I'm using php to display image(s) and accompanying  text (This is done using a WHILE loop) See below:

```
While (true) {

echo "
       <h2>$post_title</h2> 
       <img src ='new_images/$post_image' width='200' height='200'/>  // Image
       <div>$post_content</div> ";   // Text 
}
```

I have used CSS to float the image left. Therefore,the accompanying text appears to the right of the image.

However, the second image and accompanying text is NOT sitting below the first. It's trying to force itself into any space to the right of the first  image

Can I use CSS to ensure the images are stacked??

I hope that above makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

add `clear:both` to your images and it should work just fine

Comment: Better yet, wrap the whole "post" in a div, and add `clear: both;` to that!